# if $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } |f(x)| = \infty$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } f(x) = \infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f: \Re \mapsto \Re$ be continuous function. How to prove that if  $\lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty }  |f(x)|  =  \infty$   then   $\lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty }  f(x)  =  \infty$  or  $\lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty }  f(x)  =  -\infty$ ?

Comment: Eventually, $|f(x)|>1$; this implies, by continuity, that $f$ eventually has a constant sign.

Comment: Counter-example to your result. Consider f(x)=[x . sin(x)] which equals to x when sin(x)=1 and which equals to (-x) when sin(x)=-1. So this function oscillates between positive and negave numbers and its absolute value tends to + infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $M > 0$ there exists $x_0 > 0$ with the property that $x > x_0$ implies $|f(x)| > M$.  In particular, $x > x_0$ implies $f(x) \not= 0$ so beyond that point $f(x)$ is either always positive or always negative.  Thus $x > x_0$ implies either $f(x) > M$ or $f(x) < -M$.

Comment: in this line you wrote "beyond that point f(x) is either always positive or always negative". but how you conclude that?

Comment: If there were points $a > x_0$ and $b > x_0$ such that $f(a) > 0$ and $f(b) < 0$, the stated hypothesis that $f$ is continuous would imply there is a point $c$ in between $a$ and $b$ (and thus $c > x_0$) for which $f(c) = 0$. This contradicts $|f(c)| > M$.